# ubuntu 16.04 global menu problem

Tags: globalmenu

Some apps (Terminal, Rhythmbox, Nautilus..) doesn't have global menu, when I reset Unity (unity --reset) global menu is back but when I restart my computer the problem is still here. Upgraded from 14.04 by the way.

---

Ok, I installed it on VM (fresh install) and the problem is here. So Ubuntu devs released a broken system... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...y/+bug/1532226

Comment: That's explained in the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/) which update-manager links to & tells you to read before upgrading…

Comment: Will there be any update to fix it?

Comment: Based on the bug report it seems like someone is working on it, but currently it's hard to find what exactly causes that bug, because nobody knows how to make it happen always (for some people it happens often, for other people like the developer almost never).

Comment: But I'm sure they will fix it as soon as they can…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application's menu missing from menu bar](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762137/applications-menu-missing-from-menu-bar)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532226), this is a bug. Though there is no ultimate fix for it, but this command can solve the problem temporarily:

```
initctl restart unity-panel-service
```

It works for me. Hope it be useful for you as well