# Application's menu missing from menu bar

Tags: 16.04, menu

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and found that menus for many applications do not show on the menu bar, as it is configured in 'Settings > Appearance'. For example: menus for Filezilla, Geary, Libreoffice Writer and Software center do not show. I have not tested every app, but I can tell you that browsers (Chrome, Firefox) do have their menus on the menu bar. In addition, if I change the configuration to show menus "in the window's title bar", they don't show either.

Any clues?

Best regards.

Comment: I too am experiencing this issue, the install was working perfectly. Today they just suddenly disappeared...

Comment: I'm not sure why, but now I seem to have all my menus back. I recently install MEGA Sync, and had to restart nautilus. So maybe that did the trick, though i'm not really sure if nautilus has anything to do with it.

Comment: Seriously, 16.04 should have never been released with this bug. That's making the release almost unusable for normal users.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a reported bug that is being addressed by the developers.

Bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532226

**Missing on Startup**

Running this command in a terminal window will bring back the menus for the current session:

```
$ initctl restart unity-panel-service
```

To save time and having to:

- Check first to see if the issue is resolved
- Open a terminal Window
- Run the command

I wrote a short script and added it to my startup apps.  The script will do all the above.  I'll have three minutes to notice if the problem is fixed of which I can disable the startup script once the bug is fixed.

There's a sound notice to nudge me to check if it has been fixed... then finally the command is automatically run.

The menus will be fixed 4 minutes after each reboot.

Script named `resetmenus.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 180
espeak "Resetting unity-panel-service"
sleep 60
initctl restart unity-panel-service
```

The script can be added to startup by typing `startup applications` in the Unity Launch Search Button.

**Disappearing during logged in session**

The script above resolves the menu problem that is always missing upon boot.  The menu subsequently disappears between boots.  When this happens I find the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Cntl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to bring up a terminal and typing `unity` as mentioned in the previous answer is ideal for that instance.

Comment: `initctl restart unity-panel-service` also works for menus disappearing during current session. Also it doesn't seem to crash open applications,. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer is the one that really solved my problem too.

Comment: for ubuntu 16.04 using systemd instead of upstart, you should issue command like this `restart unity-panel-service`. If using `initctl restart` you may get a upstart error message since 16.04 is not using upstart.

Comment: Thanks ! it works. I was going to install gnome classic menue. But I love Unity and Ubuntu though there are some bugs. Seems Ubuntu 12.04 was the best one I have ever used.

Comment: // , Funny how the new `systemd` forced on Ubuntu means that boots sometimes have a problem, and sometimes don't, even for the exact same settings and files.

Comment: // , Also, would you be willing to include a link to how to open a terminal window?

Comment: // , This no longer works. Both `restart unity-panel-service` and `initctl restart unity-panel-service` do not work on Ubuntu 16.04: `restart: Name "com.ubuntu.Upstart" does not exist`.

Comment: @NathanBasanese You can open a terminal by clicking on the Launch Menu button and typing `terminal`.

Comment: OOh yeahhh,, `initctl restart unity-panel-service` works.

Comment: It didn't help for me on ubuntu 16.04. Just stopping unity-panel-service brings the top menu and be removed when starting it again. However the side bar and close menu doesn't appear. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't work for 18.04 because the packages containing `initctl` are only available from the previous release and conflicting with the existing packages.

Comment: I got `initctl: command not found` (Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 30):

Apparently it is a confirmed bug on the release... A fix is being investigated. You can see the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532226)

The temporary solution is to open a terminal with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and typing `unity`. This will cause the UI to reset and fix the problem. You'll need to so this every time you boot and it happens.

It is still unknown why it happens, but it affects about 30% of boots.

Comment: I'll edit the answer afterwards once I find again the bug report. Got lost on my tab history heh...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I hope that it gets fixed soon.

Comment: This brought the menu back but crashed half of the programs I was running (such as Chrome, Atom IDE, Filezilla). This is a pretty serious bug, I'm looking forward to a real solution.

Comment: Don't you mean `Alt+Ctrl+T`?

Comment: @L. you are totally right, just edited.

Comment: Warning: This will kill all the running user-applications !! See the [other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/765744/173003) for a better solution.

Comment: See LD James solution, which works immediately, although you may have to do this after each boot until the bug is fixed. That should be the accepted answer!

Comment: this works to me.  on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: // , It's too bad about the widely hated `systemd` making boots no longer deterministic...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I did what you explained:

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk
```

Thank you very much for the help, of course.
I have uninstalled 2 files (`libreoffice-gtk` and `libreoffice-gnome`) and then the menu appeared (old version).

But then I tried installing again only libreoffice-gtk:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk
```

...and opening the libreoffice, the menu appears correctly (new version).

It may be coincidence, but it worked.

Comment: // , Did the problem ever come up again?

Comment: THANKS, I had my panel disappearing each time I launched libreoffice too. However, when trying to run the 'apt purge' command, it says that it will *also* uninstall `gnome* libreoffice-gnome* libreoffice-gtk* ubuntu-mate-desktop*`... Why? I'm afraid this will break everything ^^

Comment: update: this purge won't break gnome or mate, since those are only metapackages. gnome-core & co will stay and keep functioning.

Comment: last update: reinstalling libreoffice-gtk/gnome or even libreoffice-gtk3 did not solve the problem, but **deleting `~/.config/libreoffice`** did!!

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem with applications like LibreOffice 5 and terminal and gedit. Menu bar was missing from these applications. It occurred after upgrading Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS from 14.04 LTS... I used following two commands and it worked for me...

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

setsid unity
```

Use above two commands and I hope it will work for you also...

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me in an upgrade (15.10 -> 16.04), since I couldn't fix it I created a new user and everything looks fine there.

*edit!*

With the hurry no longer there, I went back to try recovering that user profile. Eventually I managed to get a terminal for that user (use <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>... until you get a -full screen- terminal), then I was able to login as the wounded user and run this commands:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Optionally, you can use this commands to clean and reconfigure the installed packages:

```
apt install -f
dpkg-reconfigure --force
```

Comment: Added follow up, it may be of help to fix the broken user-profile.

Answer (score 1):

Run

> sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu

If this actually installs something, then you likely found the problem.
I'm not sure what is the easiest way to actually activate the appmenu, but rebooting did the job for me.

Comment: (I had previously uninstalled `indicator-appmenu` because it disabled TeXmaker's keyboard shortcuts, but that bug seems to be resolved.)