# some menubars are missing on Ubuntu 16

Tags: unity, menu

I'm new to Ubuntu (using 16.04), I've used it for about three days.
Today's issue is that the menu bars are missing from some applications: Nautilus, archive manager, Sublime Text 3 (when not run with `sudo`)*, Evince and who knows how many others. I swear they were present yesterday.

On the other hand in Firefox, LibreOffice and on many others, they are still present, for now.

I changed "show the menus for a window" under settings/appearance/behavior
both to "in the menu bar" and "in the window's title bar", but that didn't fix it.
Uninstalling and reinstalling the applications   didn't fix it either.

What can I do?

edit, pics!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO4GV.jpg

*When I open Sublime Text from the Unity Launcher or when I type `subl` in the terminal, menus are not showing. If I type `sudo subl` they do.

Comment: When you say: 'Sublime Text 3 (when not run with sudo)', you mean run from the user terminal, not as true root? Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the applications at all? Interesting question, by the way. I had something quite similar happen on a Linux installation also. Which leads me to two other questions: are you running KDE or Gnome? I'm hazarding a guess at KDE, but might be wrong... Also, did this occur after an update at all, or after an update got stuck? Particularly after a command-line update workaround advised by members of a forum? Just a guess but might be related...

Comment: Um, silly question but can you please post the screenshot of what is missing ? Also, since you're new to Ubuntu, are you aware that such menus as File , Edit, View are all placed onto the top bar ? They're not on the window itself

Comment: >When you say: 'Sublime Text 3 (when not run with sudo)', you mean run from the user terminal, not as true root?     

***** When I open Sublime Text from the Unity Launcher or when I type `subl` in the terminal, menus are not showing. If I type `sudo subl` they do.

Comment: >Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the applications at all?

***** Yep, nothing changed. With Sublime Text 3 I even deleted the settings folder to reinitialize it.

Comment: >Interesting question, by the way. I had something quite similar happen on a Linux installation also. Which leads me to two other questions: are you running KDE or Gnome? I'm hazarding a guess at KDE, but might be wrong
***** Well, you tell me: 
`echo $DESKTOP_SESSION and echo $GDMSESSION` outputs `ubuntu`
comparing screenshots looks like Unity
and `$ pgrep -l "gnome|kde|mate|cinnamon|lxde|xfce|jwm" `
outputs
`26 kdevtmpfs
1309 gnome-keyring-d
1361 gnome-session-b
1684 polkit-gnome-au
1698 gnome-software
7636 gnome-terminal-
8520 tomate-gtk `

Comment: >... Also, did this occur after an update at all, or after an update got stuck? Particularly after a command-line update workaround advised by members of a forum? Just a guess but might be related…

***** Honestly it’s an issue after another issue, updating the video drivers felt like a fantasy movie quest and, 
as I don’t understand many things yet, I could have touched something wrong. But still in that time lapse I haven’t been doing anything weird

Comment: >Um, silly question but can you please post the screenshot of what is missing ? Also, since you're new to Ubuntu, are you aware that such menus as File , Edit, View are all placed onto the top bar ? They're not on the window itself 
***** Sure thing, btw I’ve already messed with that option without having any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

damn Linux, turns out it wasn't my fault!

[Application's menu missing from menu bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762137/applications-menu-missing-from-menu-bar)
answered Apr 27 at 1:06 by rlam12:

> Apparently it is a confirmed bug on the release... A fix is being investigated. You can see the bug report here
>   The temporary solution is to open a terminal with `ALT + CONTROL + T` and typing `unity`. This will cause the UI to reset and fix the problem. You'll need to so this every time you boot and it happens.
>   It is still unknown why it happens, but it affects about 30% of boots.