# Application menu missing on menu bar / windows title bar after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, upgrade, appmenu

I upgraded from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS and somehow the application menu in any window, was not showing anymore.

I tried changing the settings in the appearance config but with no luck (location menu bar vs window title bar and always visibe).

There is a [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762137/applications-menu-missing-from-menu-bar) here but it involved a fresh install and none of the answers worked for me.

How can I get my application menu back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around I found [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2245570&p=13128753#post13128753) describing the same issue (but for 14.04).

The solution is simply:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu
```

Don't ask me why it was missing..