# Empty icon space in top panel

Tags: 16.04, panel, appearance, taskbar

After some time an empty space appeared at my top panel

[image: IMAGE HERE]

If I click on it, I see empty dropdown list, do you have any ideas of how can I get rid of it?  I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Do you have dropbox installed?  There is a possibility that it could be related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/how-to-fix-non-working-dropbox-icon-on-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64 but I am not 100% sure.  You might need to look also at all the startup items you have running and see what is missing that should be on the bar.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have dropbox and its icon is the most left in the image, it works fine. This might be due to some other program I installed/uninstalled in the past. Startup I have is Plank,Dropbox,Skype,SSH Agent. Is there a list of all top panel programs to display?

Comment: I haven't used Dropbox for a really long time, so I wasn't sure if that was it or not.  That's beside the point.  What Desktop Environment are you using?  Xfce4, Unity, GNOME, etc?  The only reason I ask this is that themes can change the way a DE looks and yours looks close to Xfce4 like what I am running, but I don't want to assume anything.  This can change the answers for how the bar behaves.  One that I can think of might be https://askubuntu.com/a/765744/231142 that deals with Unity.